# Is there any equivalent of calculus in a modular field?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

For example, does $\frac{dy}{dx}\equiv c\mod n$ hold any meaning? How are the rules of calculus modified to allow for this, if possible.

For a simple example, $ax\equiv b\mod n$ behaves the same as $ax=b$ for  $x\in[0,n)$, after which there is a discontinuity and then the initial interval output repeats because $ax\equiv((a\mod n)(x\mod n))\mod n$. We could therefore define $\frac{dy}{dx}\equiv a\mod n$ at all points not a multiple of $n$ for lines. It would seem apt to be able to extend this definition to at least higher order polynomials.

One may also need to keep in mind $x\mod n=\frac{x}{n}-n\lfloor{\frac{x}{n}\rfloor}$ as a real number extension for issues of continuity, although this makes derivatives even more confuddling.

Comment: I don‘t know of a concept that satisfies your question entirely, but maybe you should look into $p$-adic analysis, which is kind of a generalisation of what you‘re talking about. Of course you can manipulate polynomials and power series mod $n$, too. Maybe have a look at Teichmüller lifts which are a kind of discrete notion of a limit mod $n$.